# User not updated after database direct change/session seems not to be cleared

Tags: jsf, session, authentication, eclipselink, logout

I have a JSF application in which a user can login via a loginBean as follows:

```
public String doLogin() {
        Query query = ejbFacade.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("loginQuery",  User.class);
    query.setParameter("email", username);
    query.setParameter("pw", pw);
    try {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", query.getSingleResult());
        return "/loggedin/index?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (NoResultException userNotFoundEx) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login, try again"));
        return "/public/login";
    }
}
```

Then I have a userRegistrationBean that produces a @LoggedIn user. This bean is SessionScoped so when one registrates one is already logged in.
To know if the user came from a "direct login" or a "registration login" I perform the following:

```
@Produces @Logado
public User getLoggedUser() {
    if (this.user.getId() == null) { //means no user was registered this time

        this.loggedUser = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("user");

        if (this.loggedUser != null) {
            return this.loggedUser;
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("There's no user logged in.");
    }

    this.loggedUser = this.user;
    return this.loggedUser;
}
```

My logout method:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

The problem is that when I go directly to the database and change, lets say the some user name, and I enter the system with that login, the name is not up to date.
Let's say my databse is empty. Then I register a user -> logout -> manually change something in database -> login that user. The user data is not updated.
It seems that the app never reads from the database again, but the eclipse link shows
a new query on every login.
Can someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink has a second level cache that you will need to manage if you are going to make changes outside of JPA.  Details on the cache are here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching

The simplest solution is to call em.refresh(entity) if you know changes have been made, but EclipseLink also has query hints that can refresh.  As a more extreme option, you can disable the shared cache, but this should be a last resort as the cache can improve performance in most applications.